# Muse jQuery IE compatibility issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, muse

This is a long shot. I have been given this website which was created in Adobe Muse. The code is a mess with more than a dozen CSS files and script files. I am going to re-build the website from scratch but for the mean time the website is needed ASAP, though there are two main issues.

1. There page is pushed to the left leaving a margin on the right. Responsive hasn't been added yet but I can't work out why the margin is appearing.
2. When images are hovered over, text with an orange background appears, though on IE9, the events don't fire up.

Is there any fallback code for this issue?

**HTML**

```
<div class="PamphletWidget clearfix colelem" id="pamphletu1152">
    <!-- none box -->
    <div class="ThumbGroup clearfix grpelem" id="u1159">
        <!-- none box -->
        <div class="popup_anchor">
            <div class="Thumb popup_element clearfix" id="u1160">
                <!-- group -->
                <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u1235-6">
                    <!-- content -->
                    <p id="u1235-2">Richard Bizley</p>
                    <p id="u1235-4">Head of Professional Practice</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup_anchor" id="u1153popup">
        <div class="ContainerGroup clearfix" id="u1153">
            <!-- stack box -->
            <div class="Container clearfix grpelem" id="u1155">
                <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u1701-25">
                    <!-- content -->
                    <p id="u1701-2">Richard Bizley</p>
                    <p id="u1701-4">Head of Professional Practice</p>
                    <p id="u1701-6">+44 (0)1223 224039</p>
                    <p class="LifeSci-Ppl" id="u1701-9"><a class="nonblock" href="mailto:richard.bizley@avidity-ip.com">richard.bizley@avidity-ip.com</a>

                    </p>
                    <p id="u1701-10">&nbsp;</p>
                    <p id="u1701-12">Fellow of the Chartered Institute of Patent Attorneys (UK) (1975); European Patent Attorney (1978); UK Registered Trade Mark Agent (1990); European Trade Mark Attorney (1996); Patent Agent Litigator (Litigation Certificate) (2002); BA (Hons) and MA in Biochemistry (Oxford).</p>
                    <p id="u1701-14">As a biochemist of very considerable experience in the patent profession, Richard’s career has encompassed all of the major biotech patenting developments since the European Patent Office opened in 1978. In the late 1970s, Richard provided the European representation for Cetus Corporation covering matters ranging from protein isolation, through initial recombinant technology applications, to the first PCR cases. Richard advised the MRC in relation to the early genomics cases, and filed the MRC’s initial genomics case as well as spin-off technology from the human genome project.</p>
                    <p id="u1701-16">Richard has provided representation in a list of very high profile cases at the European Patent Office at all levels, including PCR, the Harvard oncomouse case, the recombinant relaxin case, patentability of genomics (including obtaining patent grant on appeal for a ZymoGenetics case which has been regarded as seminal in biotech patentability, having been relied upon in judgements of the English Court of Appeal and Supreme Court), Schering AG’s successful attack against Biogen’s IFN Beta case, Protein Design Labs and humanised antibodies, and many many more.</p>
                    <p id="u1701-18">Richard is recognised as one of the leading practitioners in Europe in relation to oppositions and related contentious proceedings, having very considerable experience in running opposition teams and related litigation. His experience of and familiarity with the Boards of Appeal at the EPO is of immense value to clients and, as the Director responsible for contentious proceedings, Richard inevitably deals with clients at all levels and in all commercial circumstances.</p>
                    <p id="u1701-20">Richard has handled a number of standard and “non-conventional” cases spanning, antibodies, vaccines and small molecule drugs. This unique experience resulted in Richard’s filing of SPC applications for each of the only two antibody drug conjugates (ADCs) presently approved in Europe.</p>
                    <p id="u1701-22">Richard is continuously recognised in peer review assessments of leading practitioners.</p>
                    <p id="u1701-23">&nbsp;</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
(function (a, b) {
    b.widget("Widget.TabGroup", b.Widget.RadioGroup, {
        defaultOptions: {
            defaultIndex: 0,
            hoverClass: "wp-tab-hover",
            downClass: "wp-tab-down",
            disabledClass: "wp-tab-disabled",
            checkedClass: "wp-tab-active",
            disabled: !1,
            toggleStateEnabled: !1
        },
        selectTab: function (a) {
            this.checkButton(a)
        },
        checkButton: function (a) {
            var b = this._getElement(a),
                g = this._getElementIndex(b),
                b = {
                    tab: b,
                    tabIndex: g
                };
            this.trigger("wp-tab-before-select", b);
            this._super.prototype.checkButton.apply(this, arguments);
            this.trigger("wp-tab-select", b)
        }
    });
    a.fn.wpTabGroup = function (a) {
        new b.Widget.TabGroup(this, a);
        return this
    }
})(jQuery, WebPro, window, document);
```